# I have loaded Excel files into .NET using LINQ, now how to bulk insert data into DB (oracle) tables?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

```
var ex = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"c:\test.xls");
var data = from c in ex.Worksheet<testClass>("Sheet 1")
           select c;
```

I have added a data connection to Oracle Database.
Is there a straight forward way to bulk insert this data?

P.S. 
I am a beginner in .NET 4 learning, have gone through other links talking about bulk insert but somehow cannot connect.
This is a windows form, where I read excel files on click of a button.

Comment: can this data object directly inserted into table in Database?